# how to alter a table and give new unique value depending on other column?

Tags: sql

I have a table which includes authors and articles.
I have given the articles unique ID's and want to do the same for authors.
How can i alter my table to create a new column called authorID
and give each author a unique ID. When i try i can either change it up one author at a time with the update funktion or use int identity. The problem usint int identity is that the same author might show up multipletimes and should get the same number as he/she did earlier.
My question is therefore: Is there an SQL funktion where you alter a column (authorID) and give a unique iD everytime you find a author which doesn't already have a unique ID?

Comment: Start with creating an authors table, where you give each author an authorID. Then you can update the articles table.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)